# How to attach my domain with bind in real www

Tags: ubuntu, debian, networking, dns, bind

How to attach my domain with bind in real wwwI install bind9, with apache. By God's very grace every thing went smooth.
my dig, host, nslookup and ping provide this info:

my system ip address: 59.177.154.251

my domain name: imsingh.com

my domain registrar: GoDaddy.com

When i write imsingh.com in my system browser's address bar the website opens properly.

**my question: What I need todo further so that imsingh.com opens the website hosted on my system.** when I or You, or anyone else clicks [www.imsingh.com](http://imsingh.com) then *the website hosted on my system is not launched.* I want to know how **i should change namesever with ns1.imsingh.com & ns2.imsingh.com** at GoDaddy.com because when i change them GoDaddy says `nameserver not registered`

```
            # dig imsingh.com

            ; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> imsingh.com
            ;; global options: +cmd
            ;; Got answer:
            ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 15453
            ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 2

            ;; QUESTION SECTION:
            ;imsingh.com.           IN  A

            ;; ANSWER SECTION:
            imsingh.com.        86400   IN  A   59.177.154.251

            ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
            imsingh.com.        86400   IN  NS  NS1.imsingh.com.
            imsingh.com.        86400   IN  NS  NS2.imsingh.com.

            ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
            NS1.imsingh.com.    86400   IN  A   59.177.154.251
            NS2.imsingh.com.    86400   IN  A   59.177.154.251

            ;; Query time: 0 msec
            ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
            ;; WHEN: Fri Aug  9 16:01:25 2013
            ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 113

            # host imsingh.com
            imsingh.com has address 59.177.154.251
            imsingh.com mail is handled by 10 MX1.imsingh.com.

            # nslookup imsingh.com
            Server:     127.0.0.1
            Address:    127.0.0.1#53

            Name:   imsingh.com
            Address: 59.177.154.251


            # ping imsingh.com
            PING imsingh.com (59.177.154.251) 56(84) bytes of data.
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=1 ttl=254 time=0.539 ms
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=2 ttl=254 time=0.535 ms
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=3 ttl=254 time=0.529 ms
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=4 ttl=254 time=0.534 ms
            64 bytes from IMSINGH.COM (59.177.154.251): icmp_req=5 ttl=254 time=0.534 ms
            ^C
            --- imsingh.com ping statistics ---
            5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3997ms
            rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.529/0.534/0.539/0.014 ms
```

Data for ip address

```
            # dig -x 59.177.154.251

            ; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> -x 59.177.154.251
            ;; global options: +cmd
            ;; Got answer:
            ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 27574
            ;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

            ;; QUESTION SECTION:
            ;251.154.177.59.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

            ;; ANSWER SECTION:
            251.154.177.59.in-addr.arpa. 604800 IN  PTR IMSINGH.COM.

            ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
            59.in-addr.arpa.    604800  IN  NS  IMSINGH.COM.

            ;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
            IMSINGH.COM.        86400   IN  A   59.177.154.251

            ;; Query time: 0 msec
            ;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
            ;; WHEN: Fri Aug  9 16:05:06 2013
            ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100


            # host 59.177.154.251
            251.154.177.59.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer IMSINGH.COM.


            # host 59.177.154.251
            251.154.177.59.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer IMSINGH.COM.


            # ping 59.177.154.251
            PING 59.177.154.251 (59.177.154.251) 56(84) bytes of data.
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=1 ttl=254 time=0.679 ms
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=2 ttl=254 time=0.529 ms
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=3 ttl=254 time=0.533 ms
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=4 ttl=254 time=0.689 ms
            64 bytes from 59.177.154.251: icmp_req=5 ttl=254 time=0.523 ms
            ^C
            --- 59.177.154.251 ping statistics ---
            5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3998ms
            rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.523/0.590/0.689/0.080 ms
```

Comment: Too many unknown variables. How are you connected to the internet? Presumably you're using a router with NAT?

Comment: @Shadur, yes, Im using router with NAT. May I ask you -- What unknown variables".

Comment: What kind of internet connection you have, what kind of router you're using, how your server is connected to that router, and so on...

Comment: my ifconfig give this 
`eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 48:5b:39:c4:d1:01  
          inet addr:192.168.1.2  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::4a5b:39ff:fec4:d101/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:36843 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27401 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:45176792 (43.0 MiB)  TX bytes:3863697 (3.6 MiB)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0x8000 
`

Comment: and this 
`lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:2189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2189 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:350819 (342.5 KiB)  TX bytes:350819 (342.5 KiB)`

Comment: Any Suggestion now ...

Comment: Answer amended. Move comments to there, please.

Answer (score 1):

I did find this nugget in your question (hint: it helps being as specific as possible about what your problem is, and try to avoid superflouous information; if more information is needed, it'll usually be asked for in comments in short order, and you can edit your question to include it)...

> I want to know how i should change namesever with ns1.imsingh.com & ns2.imsingh.com at GoDaddy.com because when i change them GoDaddy says `nameserver not registered`

That part is easy. Or, well, not necessarily easy, but if you know how DNS works, it's easy to see what's wrong, and that should help you fix it. Since your delegated-to name servers are in the same domain that you are delegating, you need to provide what's known as *glue records* through the registrar, so that anyone querying the root name servers don't have the catch-22 situation of needing to know the addresses of your name servers before they can find the addresses of your name servers. These glue records also need to be maintained if the IP address of your name server(s) ever change.

Normally, that's done either as a separate step before you enter the delegation records, or together with the delegated-to host name as a separate IP field. I don't know exactly how GoDaddy in particular does it, but there should be somewhere in their administration interface where you can provide glue record data.

You may also be interested in [Clarification of why DNS zone files require NS records](https://serverfault.com/q/526278/58408) over on ServerFault, which explains why and how glue records are used.

**That said,** you may want to reconsider running your own server if you need to ask about something like this. Aside from such things as connection stability, power supply issues, hardware redundancy and so on, do keep in mind that the Internet of today is a hostile place, and any server not properly secured and actively managed is likely to be broken into within a very short period of time. Unless you have some *very* specific need *and* you are up to the task of managing an Internet-connected server, I'd strongly suggest that you consider just getting a web hosting account somewhere instead.

Comment: That said, though (heh) -- doing a lookup of imsingh.com from the outside does resolve properly, I'm just not getting any data back. I think I'm on the right track with his router/NAT issues.

Comment: @shadur i have done port forwarding properly to 192.168.1.2. and if i write 59.177.154.251 in browser from other outer systems my site opens. but imsingh.com does not ...

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the response I get when I try to browse to that server (no data received) I'm assuming that you're running your personal server on your own internet connection, which is almost certainly behind a router that's performing [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) at the very least and likely includes firewall services that blocks anything coming from outside that you haven't explicitly told it to let through.

Without a great deal more information I can only suggest the following troubleshooting actions:

1. Check your router/firewall settings and ensure that inbound traffic to port 80 on your external IP gets routed via DNAT (Destination NAT) to the internal IP address of your webserver.
2. Check that your webserver listens on *all* IP addresses, not just localhost (some distributions default to that for security reasons).
3. Verify that your ISP doesn't block inbound port 80 because they don't want their customers running private webservers. Probably not, but it's worth checking to be sure.

**EDIT** From the information in your comments, it looks like you'll need to configure your router to forward port 80 coming in from outside to 192.168.1.2 on the inside. How the particular router that you have does this is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Please let me know, what more information you need, thanks

Comment: You're going to have to check all those three on your own, although I suspect that only the first is your *actual* problem. As to how to set up DNAT, that depends entirely on what kind of router you're using.

Comment: i have done port forwarding properly to 192.168.1.2. and if i write 59.177.154.251 in browser from other outer systems my site opens. but imsingh.com does not ...